# Blueprintjs icons not displaying correctly on pages

Tags: css, reactjs, icons, blueprintjs

I am currently working on an old React application that has blueprintjs version 1. I upgraded to version 4. I followed the documentation.
The icons are currently not displaying correctly. See image.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
  <div className="hg-RightMenu hg-toolbar">
    <ul className="hg-RightMenu__list">
      <li className="hg-RightMenu__list__item">
        <SidebarToggle icon="bp4-icon-user" tooltip="User Profile" name="PROFILE" />
        <div className="hg-badge">{messagesCount}</div>
      </li>
      <li className="hg-RightMenu__list__item">
        <SidebarToggle icon="bp4-icon-history" tooltip="Recent Searches" name="SEARCH_HISTORY" />
      </li>
      <li className="hg-RightMenu__list__item">
        <SidebarToggle icon="bp4-icon-floppy-disk" tooltip="Saved Searches" name="SAVED_SEARCHES" />
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: it will be easy to know what is the problem if you provided some code !

Comment: @monim I provided some code.

Comment: Can you still provide the CSS for the icons?

Comment: import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
                                                                                                                               
import '@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css';
                                                                                                                               
import '@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css';

Answer (score 0):

What is the implementation of `<SidebarToggle>` in your code example? That's not a Blueprint component, so I'm guessing you're taking the `icon="bp4-icon-user"` prop there and forwarding it to a Blueprint API. You likely just have to drop the "bp4-icon-" prefix. There were a number of changes to icons APIs in Blueprint v2.0, see the [changelog here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Blueprint-2.0#blueprintjsicons).